# Hash value of String that would be stable across iOS releases?

Tags: ios, swift, hash, nsstring, hashcode

In documentation `String.hash` for iOS it says:

> You should not rely on this property having the same hash value across
>   releases of OS X.

(strange why they speak of OS X in iOS documentation)

Well, I need a hasshing function that will not change with iOS releases. It can be simple I do not need anything like SHA. Is there some library for that?

There is another question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28301891/311865) but the accepted (and only) answer there simply states that we should respect the note in documentation.

Comment: if it can be simple, why not use an [MD5 hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2018626/1219956) edit: [swift version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123518/how-to-use-cc-md5-method-in-swift-language)

Comment: @Fonix Yes, that could be solution. There are many answer to the question you are linking - could you recommend any of those with stable and fast MD5 hash implementation in Swift?

Comment: see the second link in my first comment, but otherwise there are tons of solutions with a quick google

Answer (score 27):

Here is a non-crypto hash, for Swift 3:

```
 func strHash(_ str: String) -> UInt64 {
    var result = UInt64 (5381)
    let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
    for b in buf {
        result = 127 * (result & 0x00ffffffffffffff) + UInt64(b)
    }
    return result
 }
```

It was derived somewhat from a C++11 constexpr

```
    constexpr uint64_t str2int(char const *input) {
    return *input                      // test for null terminator
    ? (static_cast<uint64_t>(*input) + // add char to end
       127 * ((str2int(input + 1)      // prime 127 shifts left almost 7 bits
               & 0x00ffffffffffffff))) // mask right 56 bits
    : 5381;                            // start with prime number 5381
}
```

Unfortunately, the two don't yield the same hash. To do that you'd need to reverse the iterator order in strHash:

```
for b in buf.reversed() {...}
```

But that will run 13x slower, somewhat comparable to the djb2hash String extension that I got from https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-hashable/

Here are some benchmarks, for a million iterations:

```
hashValue execution time: 0.147760987281799
strHash execution time:   1.45974600315094
strHashReversed time:    18.7755110263824
djb2hash execution time: 16.0091370344162
sdbmhash crashed
```

For C++, the str2Int is roughly as fast as Swift 3's hashValue:

```
str2int execution time: 0.136421
```

Comment: Slightly more condensed version of Warren's first answer as a computed property on a String extension:

`[UInt8](utf8).reduce(UInt64(5381)) { 127 * ($0 & 0x00ffffffffffffff) + UInt64($1) }`

Comment: Is there any way to reverse this operation? To get `String` value from the hash

Comment: @Adam Nope. Most hashes lose information. The main utility of a hash is to shorten a long value into a shorter value that doesn't collide with other shortened values.