# String.hashValue not unique after reset app when build in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

I have a "get hash of string by `String.hashValue`" code, that I added it below. This code worked well in Xcode 9.4.1.

Worked well means that whenever I close app and re-open it, the result of `hashValue` is same (unique)

```
private func cacheName(of url: String) -> String {
    // The url is url of a png image, for example www.imageurl.com/image.png
    return "\(url.hashValue)"
}
```

When I build my Project in Xcode 10 the result changes everytime I restart the app (close and open app again). The version of iOS, device, Swift version is same. So I think the problem is Xcode 10 has change something that effect to the `hashValue` (maybe configure when build app ??)

If I use the `String.hash` instead of, it works well. But in the previous version, I saved the `hashValue` result, so I don't want to change it.

How can I keep the result of `String.hashValue` unique in every time. Or any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue ALWAYS (since Swift 1.0) stated that “Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Swift 4.2 has implemented [SE-0206](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md): Hashable Enhancements. This introduces a new Hasher struct that provides a ***randomly seeded*** hash function. That's why the hashing results differ everytime (since the seed is random). You can find the implementation of the Hasher struct, with the generation of a random seed, [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Hasher.swift).

If you want a stable hash value associated to a String, accross devices and app lauches, you could use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43149500/2907715) by [Warren Stringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419740/warren-stringer):

```
let str = "Hello"

func strHash(_ str: String) -> UInt64 {
    var result = UInt64 (5381)
    let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
    for b in buf {
        result = 127 * (result & 0x00ffffffffffffff) + UInt64(b)
    }
    return result
}

strHash(str)     //177798404835661
```

Or have [these](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) couple of extensions defined on String:

```
extension String {
    var djb2hash: Int {
        let unicodeScalars = self.unicodeScalars.map { $0.value }
        return unicodeScalars.reduce(5381) {
            ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
        }
    }

    var sdbmhash: Int {
        let unicodeScalars = self.unicodeScalars.map { $0.value }
        return unicodeScalars.reduce(0) {
            (Int($1) &+ ($0 << 6) &+ ($0 << 16)).addingReportingOverflow(-$0).partialValue
        }
    }
}

"Hello".djb2hash    //210676686969
"Hello".sdbmhash    //5142962386210502930
```

*(This is executed on Xcode 10, Swift 4.2)*

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I tested it in Swift 4 and it only error in Xcode 10

Comment: @QuocNguyen what is the error message you're getting? And what code have you tried?

Comment: the sdbmhash throws `thread 1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0xXXXXXXXX)` in swift 4

Comment: @PranoyC I can't reproduce the error on Swift `4.2` as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Strangely enough, when I test using strings like "hello" or "blah", it works fine. But if I test using "gamedev", it makes it crash with that error. I am relatively new to swift, so I don't understand the method well enough to determine why though. Can you test using "gamedev"?

Comment: @PranoyC: Well spotted! That was due to integer overflow. I've updated the answer

Comment: @ielyamani thank you! Works now! Such a coincidence that it failed on the first string I tested on lol

Comment: Slightly more condensed version of Warren's answer as a computed property on a String extension:

`[UInt8](utf8).reduce(UInt64(5381)) { 127 * ($0 & 0x00ffffffffffffff) + UInt64($1) }`