# Swift hashValue not consistent (and is often negative)

Tags: swift

I am trying to use `hashValue` function for `String` in Swift. Unfortunately, the value returned isn't consistent and often is negative. Is this the expected behaviour?

How can I get a consistent Int value for a string in Swift?

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"? And yes, negative values are normal.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue): “Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program.”

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52440502/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35882103/1187415

Comment: The Option-click documentation for it says, "Summary

An unsigned integer that can be used as a hash table address."

If it's an unsigned integer, it should never be negative, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 offers a new way that you can get hashes depending how you want. Just subscribe to `Hashable` protocol and implement `hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` in your class:

```
class CustomClass:Equatable, Hashable {
    var id: Int32 = 0
    var name: String?

    init() {
    }



    static func == (lhs: CustomClass, rhs: CustomClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
    // hash value is calculated based on id, name parameters
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct, but it does not change the fact that the hash value  changes with each program execution. It does not answer the question *“How can I get a consistent Int value for a string in Swift?”*

Comment: You shouldn’t rely on specific hash values or save them across executions. On the rare occasion that you would need deterministic behavior, you can set the flag `SWIFT_DETERMINISTIC_HASHING` to disable random hash seeds.

Comment: where do I set SWIFT_DETERMINISTIC_HASHING? can. this be done in code for particular hashes?